# move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Tags: rust, copy

I tried to make a function that returns function application of kth elements in vector. Here is my code:

```
fn action<T, F: Fn(T) -> T>(f: F, k: usize, v: Vec<T>) -> Option<T> {
    if k >= v.len() {
        return None;
    }
    Some(f(v[k]))
}
```

and I got this error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<T>`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:12
  |
5 |     Some(f(v[k]))
  |            ^^^^ move occurs because value has type `T`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
fn action<T: Copy, F: Fn(T) -> T>(f: F, k: usize, v: Vec<T>) -> Option<T>
{
    if k >= v.len() {
        return None;
    }
    Some(f(v[k]))
}
```

Here is another way:

```
fn action<T, F: Fn(&T) -> T>(f: F, k: usize, v: Vec<T>) -> Option<T>
{
    if k >= v.len() {
        return None;
    }
    Some(f(&v[k]))
}
```

Here is third way:

```
fn action<T: Clone, F: Fn(T) -> T>(f: F, k: usize, v: Vec<T>) -> Option<T>
{
    if k >= v.len() {
        return None;
    }
    Some(f(v[k].clone()))
}
```

The best way depends on your particular data. Of course it is more efficient to pass a reference than to clone the data into the function but if you operate over vector of numbers it does not matter.